# How does third party send bulk emails from gmail?

Tags: email, smtp

Gmail has a 24 hour rolling period limit of 2000 emails, outlook has a limit of 1000 emails and all other service providers has a limit.

How does Saleshandy and sendpluse send almost 10k emails per day from gmail when the limit exists? What should I do if I want to send such number of emails? Is it possible using python?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail and outlook both do indeed have certain restrictions and limits when it comes to the number of emails that can be sent out in a day; unfortunate I know.

I am Vatsal from SalesHandy, and I will explain the process of sending 10,000 emails from Gmail (& outlook) all at once.

SalesHandy’s **mass mailing feature** with automated follow-up lets you schedule as many emails as possible and yes, we are talking more than 10,000 emails too.

We mentioned that you can schedule all of these emails to be sent at once, but the sending will be limited by your email service provider's daily email sending limit. It is not recommended to email blasts at once because it may harm your email account's reputation and cause your emails to end up in the recipient's spam box.

Mail Merge Campaigns can be sent using SalesHandy.

If you wish to know more on how exactly one goes about this process, you can read our detailed blog here - [Gmail](https://www.saleshandy.com/blog/send-10000-emails-using-gmail-2/) / [Outlook](https://www.saleshandy.com/mail-merge-outlook/).

Feel free to ask me any other questions you have! :)